# How do I dynamically create page in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Actually, I want to design an app with each user has different pages. For example UserA has X and Y pages, UserB has X and Z pages.

When UserA logged the app, UserA can see X and Y in his dashboard and can click and redirect these pages

When UserB logged the app, UserB can see X and Z in his dashboard and can click and redirect these pages

I looked some examples, but they only explain dynamically create component. Yeah with these examples, I can show their X and Y, Y and Z in their dashboard. However, I want it these X,Y,Z should be dynamic pages.

I hope, I could tell my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Changing page in dynamic manner is not difficult itself. For example, root React component can view/match current URL/entry in History API, or some information in JWT or InitialState, and dependent on it perform render appropriate child Component, which is Page in your terms.

Difficulties begin with that moment when you want that the source code of pages was not visible to all users. Or there is a lot of pages that bundle with them begins to take too much place, at the same time and load time in the browser. But also in this case there is a decision - see `webpack chunks` https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/